# Question about the transfer function found from state space model

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, state-space, root-locus

I'll make up a problem to explain what I'm having trouble with. $$\dot x=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-5&-6\end{bmatrix}x+\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}u=Ax+Bu\\\\y=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\end{bmatrix}x=Cx$$

Now because of the matrix form we can easily get the transfer function $$T(s)=\frac{s}{s^2+6s+5}$$

That's usally how the problems start. At some point I'm given that a value from the matrix changes, say -5 becomes κ-5, altering the transfer function. Basically, I have to draw the root locus as k changes but in order to do that I must know if what I've found is the **open loop** or the **closed loop** transfer function. Which one is it?

Comment: Please upload a complete 'genuine' problem. The wording may be important.

Comment: It isn't @Chu , I've talked to some other students. They all find the problems incomplete and missing info. I'll delete all the incomplete questions I've uploaded or edit them and add the full answer.

Comment: Clearly, the TF in this question is a CLTF - the highest state is a function of the input and the lower states. Hence setting the denominator = 0 gives the CE. For the root locus, one of the parameters is varied from 0 to infinity.